# C control reaches end of non void function

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int get_proper_int(string prompt);

int main(void)
{
    int i = get_proper_int("Height:");
    printf("%i\n",i);
}

int get_proper_int(string prompt) 
{  
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("%s",prompt);
    } while (n<1||n>8);  
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("#\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The `do`..`while` loop works when I `return n;` at end of loop...and for loop works on its own too...

Answer (score 3):

You declare `get_proper_int` to return a value of type `int`, but there's no `return` statement anywhere in the function.

Add it to the end of the function:

```
int get_proper_int(string prompt) 
{  
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("%s",prompt);
    } while (n<1||n>8);  
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("#\n");
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to return nothing?

Comment: @ToddChoi set the return type to `void`

Answer (score 1):

You declared `get_proper_int` to return an `int`.

#### Where is your `return` statement?

```
int get_proper_int(string prompt)
```